# How to change the height of a pane in highstock?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to drag and change the height of highstock pane in the demo [here](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume). Something like we can do for webstock [here](http://www.webstockcharts.com/stock-charts).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforurtantley this option is not possible, but I advice to post your suggestion on uservoice:  http://highcharts.uservoice.com/

Comment: Requested the option last week in the website... Lets see if I get time will make one and circulate: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/5025441-resize-pane-height-dynamically-by-mouse-drag