# Combining drag of jquery to change highcharts Height using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

**BACKGROUND:**

I have following two examples with me:

1: Change the height of a div using drag with jquery (not jqueryui). (http://jsfiddle.net/QpqX8/)`c`

2: Change the height of highcharts div due to window resize using CSS. [Link](http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/responsive-height-and-width-t25780/) and [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/anuqav/1/edit)

**SOLUTION REQUIRED:**

I want to combine above two examples so that when I drag the div boundary, the highcharts height should change (but not width).

I am a novice in CSS and tried a few combinations of taking part of code from one and merging with another.... but sadly not able to make it work. If anyone can help me pick out the solution from this, it will be great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/QpqX8/128/

Just in your drag method add `setSize()` to resize chart:

```
drag: function (event, ui) { 
    var height = ui.offset.top; 
    $("#container").highcharts().setSize(null, height); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel. Just one addon quest to you (since I have seen you answer expert level highcharts question). For the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279359/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-pane-in-highstock , I intend to add a boundary div between the panes and link the height of the pane to it... can you tell me where to do it in the highcharts source code.  I think aftre that the solution should not be much difficult and then  I can publish the answer for others who may need it.

Comment: As Sebastian said, it's not supported in Highstock, sorry. What comes to my mind is to use yAxis.update() with new height for top, and new top for bottom axis.